# Renaming google sheet worksheet causes dataframe coding error

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets

So I've written my code but when someone changes the google sheet worksheet name from the original 'Sheet 1' to something else, for example 'Students'. I would need to change my code as below

```
sh=wb.worksheet('Sheet1')
```

change to

```
sh=wb.worksheet('Students')
```

Is there a way to skip doing this all the time when someone changes the sheet name? Does google sheet have a unique hidden name for each sheet?

Comment: how many worksheets you have in the book?

Comment: I have 2 worksheets